# How to copy the current line(s) out to a new file?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, file-operations

I'm reading through a very large web service log, and I want to pull a single line out from the file, and write it to a new file.

The log lines consist of web service request XML, so they are long and unwieldy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`w` can operate on ranges, so you can do:

```
:.w foo
```

From [`:help :w`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Awrite):

```
:[range]w[rite]! [++opt] {file}
                    Write the specified lines to {file}.  Overwrite an
                    existing file.
```

Any range would do, so the following will write lines N-M inclusive to file `foo`:

```
:N,Mw foo
```

The `.` in the first command stands for the current line. See [`:help :range`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3Arange) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, this command worked ... `:34908,34914w ~/webservicelogextract.txt`

Comment: Note that most (all?) commands that take a range also work from Visual mode. When you type `:` from Visual mode, it automatically inserts `'<,'>` for you. This is a range using special marks that refer to the start and end of a Visual selection. Leave the inserted range and type in your command (it will look like `:'<,'>w webservicelogextract.txt`).